How to mount/fix USB flash drives which are not detected on a MacBook?
I have two 128GB Lexar USB flash drives. Now, when I try to connect them with my MacBook, they are not mounted automatically and they do not show up in Disk Utility too.
But my MacBook does detect the USB flash drives, because I see something happening in the /dev folder
...
brw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x100000c 19 aug 20:38 /dev/disk2s1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x100000b 19 aug 20:38 /dev/disk2 
brw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x100000e 19 aug 20:39 /dev/disk3s1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x100000d 19 aug 20:39 /dev/disk3

When I try the following it seems to hang, no output, just waiting for ever:
$> diskutil list

So my question is, is there a way I can mount this USB flash drives or maybe format it again. I find it hard te believe that both keys do not work anymore.
BTW, the USB flash drives also didn't mount on a Windows machine.

I suppose it's possible something got corrupted in the drives' partition tables in a way that's making macOS and Windows choke. You might try something like using /bin/dd to copy zeroes from /dev/zero onto the first several kilobytes and the last several kilobytes of the drive (where the partition table and backup partition table tend to be), in order to make your Mac treat it as a completely unformatted drive.

@Giacomo1968 I don't see how these are similar at all. OP's case of "not mounting at all" is a much more fundamental problem than "mounts and is readable but not writable". Those are fundamentally different things that likely require very different solutions. It would be a win for OP if OP's drives even got fixed to the point that the Question you linked to became relevant.

Please [edit] your question and add more details what happened to the USB flash drives before. Did they work before on your MacBook or on Windows? Did you do anything specific before they stopped to work? For example, did you use them to store data from a TV set or set-top box? Or format them on a Linux system? Are the two devices of the same type and same age?

Do these drives have data of any value on them?    Were they used in a no PC environment (or under Linux?)

Thanks for the help. I must say that I don't remember anymore what I did with these usb keys, I'm pretty sure I have used them though. Anyway. I noticed that when I plug it in my laptop and wait for about 5 minutes it eventually shows up in DiskUtils. When I then do 'erase' it seems, the process seems to hang (right now more than 30 minutes) on "Creating the partition table"

This question is similar to: What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
